# What is the correct way to reproject a raster from a CRS to another using Python?

Tags: python, geospatial, gdal, coordinate-transformation, rasterio

I have a raster of Land Cover data (specifically this one `/eodata/auxdata/S2GLC/2017/S2GLC_T32TMS_2017` in https://finder.creodias.eu) that uses 'epsg:32632' as CRS. I want to reproject this raster on 'epsg:21781'. This is what the raster looks like when I open it with xarray.

```py
fn = 'data/S2GLC_T32TMS_2017/S2GLC_T32TMS_2017.tif'
da = xr.open_rasterio(fn).sel(band=1, drop=True)
da
<xarray.DataArray (y: 10980, x: 10980)>
[120560400 values with dtype=uint8]
Coordinates:
  * y        (y) float64 5.2e+06 5.2e+06 5.2e+06 ... 5.09e+06 5.09e+06 5.09e+06
  * x        (x) float64 4e+05 4e+05 4e+05 ... 5.097e+05 5.097e+05 5.098e+05
Attributes:
    transform:      (10.0, 0.0, 399960.0, 0.0, -10.0, 5200020.0)
    crs:            +init=epsg:32632
    res:            (10.0, 10.0)
    is_tiled:       0
    nodatavals:     (nan,)
    scales:         (1.0,)
    offsets:        (0.0,)
    AREA_OR_POINT:  Area
    INTERLEAVE:     BAND
```

My usual workflow was to transform all the point coordinates, create my destination grid and interpolate using nearest neighbors. Something that looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pyproj
from scipy.interpolate import griddata 

y = da.y.values
x = da.x.values
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
# (n,2) point coordinates in the original CRS
src_coords = np.column_stack([xx.flatten(), yy.flatten()]) 

transformer = pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_crs('epsg:32632', 'epsg:21781')
xx, yy = transformer.transform(src_coords[:,0], src_coords[:,1])
# (n,2) point coordinates in the destination CRS, which are not on a regular grid
dst_coords = np.column_stack([xx.flatten(), yy.flatten()]) 


# I define my destination **regular** grid coordinates
x = np.linspace(620005,719995,10)
y = np.linspace(199995,100005,10)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
dst_grid = np.column_stack([xx.flatten(), yy.flatten()])

# I interpolate onto the grid
reprojected_array = griddata(
    src_coords, da.values.flatten(), dst_coords, method='nearest'
).reshape(dst_shape)
```

Although this method is fairly transparent and (apparently) error-free, it can take very long when dealing with billions of points. Recently, I discovered rasterio's `reproject` function, and I was blown away by how fast it is. This is how I implemented it:

```py
source = da.values
destination = np.zeros(dst_shape, np.int16)

res, aff = reproject(
    source,
    destination,
    src_transform=src_transform, # affine transformation from original data
    src_crs=src_crs,
    dst_transform=dst_transform, # affine transformation that corresponds to the grid defined in the other approach
    dst_crs=dst_crs,
    resampling=Resampling.nearest) # using nearest neighbors just like with scope's griddata
```

Naturally I wanted to compare the results expecting them to be the same, but they were not, as you can see in the figure.

[image]

The resolution is 10 meters so the differences are not large, but after careful comparison with precise satellite data in the 'epsg:21781' coordinates, it looks like the old approach yields better results.

So my questions are:

- why do these results differ?
- is one approach better than the other? Are there specific conditions where one should prefer one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

Griddata find nearest points in *Euclidean* distance,
on whatever map projection you give it.
Thus the nearest neighbors from a pipeline like 
  4326 data points --> reproject --> nearest-Euclidean griddata 
  query points

depend on the "reproject". Could you try `+proj=sinu +lon_0=` middle lon
for both data and query ?

What one really wants is a nearest-neighbor engine with great-circle distance,
not Euclidean distance.
The difference may be insignificant for small grids, or near the equator,
but less so in Finland -- cos 61° / cos 60° is ~ 97 %.

---

TL;DR 
Is `pyproj.transformer.Transformer.from_crs('epsg:32632', 'epsg:21781')`
"correct" ? Don't know.
I see no test suite, and a couple of issues: 
[warp.reproject() generates the wrong result](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/2052) 
[roundtrip test](https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/issues/396) \

"Nearest neighbor" is ill-defined / sensitive halfway between data points,
e.g. along the lines x or y = int + 0.5 on an int grid.
This is easy to test with KDTree.

`xarray` makes regular (Cartesian) grids easy, but afaik does not do
[curvilinear (2d) grids](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2281).